# AdapterView onClick

Tags: java, android, variables, adapter, listadapter

I have prepared working  ListAdapter and ClickListener, but I want to use variable "externalText" in ClickListener and it doesn't work. I don't know how can I do it.

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.anyArray);
if(something == something) {
String externalText = "Hello world.";

}

this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.text, array));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);


              String extraText = externalText;

              i.putExtra("text",extraText);




             startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I do 

    public String externalText = "Hello world.";

and it works. :)  but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a final modifier :

```
final String externalText = "Hello world.";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final String externalText = "Hello world.";
```

should do the trick.